# Mathematical formulation for hourly integration of power into energy quantities

Tags: integration, vectors

There is a vector $\boldsymbol{P_{el}}$ with the power values of a power plant, where every 15 minutes a power value is measured.
Now I want to create a vector $\boldsymbol{W_{el}}$ which contains the amount of energy produced for each hour, i.e. the hourly integrated power. Considering one day, $|\boldsymbol{P_{el}}| = 96$ and $|\boldsymbol{W_{el}}| = 24$.

How can I define the creation of $\boldsymbol{W_{el}}$ mathematically?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. I am going to ask you a few questions about the question you have posed. My aim is to understand your question. (1) Why do you have $P_{el}$ as a vector?, Are the voltage and the current not in phase? (2) You have stated that   $"|\boldsymbol{P_{el}}| = 96$ and $|\boldsymbol{W_{el}}| = 24"$. Do you mean that there are 96 measurements of power values and 24 values of energy-per-hour per day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definition is programming-like; $X[n]$ is the $(n+1)\text{-th}$ element of array (index $n$ starts at $0$). Convensions:

- The units of power is in Watts (W), while the unit of energy is in Watt-hour (Wh).
- The first power measurement of the day, $P_{el}[0]$, is at 00:15(am).

Then,

$$W_{el}[n] = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{m=0}^{4-1}{(P_{el}[4n+m])}$$

*Explanation:* We approximate the energy in each hour using summation of rectangles in right-end point (see figure).

[image: Summation of rectangles]

*Source: https://mathequality.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/left-right-midpoints.png*

Now, for each 15 min. interval, the area of rectangle is length x width, or $$P[i]\ \text{Watts} \times 15 \text{min.} \times \bigg(\frac{1 \text{hr.}}{60\text{min.}}\bigg) = (P[i] \times \frac{1}{4})\ \text{Wh}.$$ The $4n+m$ inside $P_{el}$ is just the indices of 15 min., 30 min., 45 min., and 60 min. rectangles for $(n+1)$-th hour. The sum of areas of these four rectangles is the $W_{el}[n]$, the energy in Watt-hour.